# Excel vba Interior.Pattern enumeration

Tags: excel, vba

I'm playing about with excel fill patterns

```
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
    .Gradient.Degree = 90
    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
End With
```

sort of thing.

Then I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpattern
This gives a table of the enumeration values for .Pattern, but xlPatternLinearGradient isn't on it.

Using the immediate window I can get the value for the constant as 4000 - Not shown on the page, but a definite allowable value

So 2 questions:
Is there an up to date table anywhere that gives all the values?
or
Is there any way to generate all the possible (legal) values of the constant?

Comment: I see that value here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.xlpattern#:~:text=xlPatternLinearGradient (Word VBA though...)  If you search `xlPattern` in the Excel VBE Object Browser (F2 to show) then you'll see `xlPatternLinearGradient`  listed there.

Comment: Ah - thanks Tim. I don't see any way to upvote your comment?